# Redirect select pages to https

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have a very simple question that for some reason I cannot figure out, and hours of searching has not helped either. Using an .htaccess file, how can I redirect just `/login.php` and `/index.php` to https, and then redirect any other page to just http? I currently use this code to redirect to https, but it redirects every page:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.ruxim.com/$1 [R]
```

thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The `%{SERVER_PORT}` variable depends on the [UseCanonicalPhysicalPort](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#usecanonicalphysicalport) in your config. If it's not setup, then you may not be able to match against that variable, easier to use `%{HTTPS}` instead.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(login|index)\.php https://www.ruxim.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^/?(login|index)\.php http://www.ruxim.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

If you don't need the redirect to non-https, then you don't need the second rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this;

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} =index.php [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} =login.php
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

I'm note 100% sure if the `[OR]` will comply suddenly in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Please apply following conditions to secure only /login.php and /index.php pages. Other pages will be work on HTTP path (non-secure pages).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# force https for /login.php and /index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(index|login)\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# don't do anything for images/css/js (leave protocol as is)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ - [NC,L]

# force http for all other URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index|login)\.php$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```